# How to fill in missing records based on yesterday's information on SQL?

Tags: sql

I am getting daily inventory information from a store and storing it onto an SQL table. The store only posts the products that have any sort of change but I need a complete list of all the products. Luckily I was able to retrieve the entire catalogue one day, so I thought if I can persist the data from yesterday's information where those product's are not in today's information then I would be good. Except, I don't know how to do that.

Example:

My table

```
Product   |  Inventory   |  Date
---------------------------------------
  A       |   1          | 2022-12-07
---------------------------------------
  B       |   2          | 2022-12-07
---------------------------------------
  C       |   3          | 2022-12-07
---------------------------------------
  D       |   4          | 2022-12-07
---------------------------------------
  E       |   5          | 2022-12-07
```

What the store posts:

```
Product   |  Inventory   |  Date
---------------------------------------
  A       |   6          | 2022-12-08
---------------------------------------
  B       |   1          | 2022-12-08
```

The rows I need as a result:

```
Product   |  Inventory   |  Date
---------------------------------------
  A       |   6          | 2022-12-08
---------------------------------------
  B       |   1          | 2022-12-08
---------------------------------------
  C       |   3          | 2022-12-08
---------------------------------------
  D       |   4          | 2022-12-08
---------------------------------------
  E       |   5          | 2022-12-08
```

Comment: Is it possible for new products to appear in the store updates? For example, `F | 1 | 2022-12-08`?

Comment: Yes it is possible @dc-ddfe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a case for LEFT JOIN and COALESCE, such as:

```
select
    coalesce( u.product, p.product ) as product,
    coalesce( u.inventory, p.inventory ) as inventory,
    coalesce( u.date, p.date) as date
from
    all_products p
    left join
    store_updates u on u.product = p.product
```

Keep in mind this will only work correctly if store_updates table only has the latest row for a product.  If you insert all store updates then you will need extra logic to get only the latest row per product.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, just one more quick question. How would I fill the date with just the u.date value. So date instead of coalesce should be filled with whatever the value for u.date is, how would I do that? @Kurt

Comment: Three suggested improvements. First, OP clarified in a comment that new products could appear in the update, so full join is probably better. Second, the date should be from `store_update`, so the last coalesce is unnecessary (`u.date` is sufficient). And lastly, this probably needs to be an update, so I suggest prefixing with `INSERT INTO all_products` and appending `DELETE FROM all_products WHERE date = yesterday`

Comment: u.date will not be sufficient by itself because products which have not been updated by the store will not have a u.date

Comment: I do not recommend deleting anything from all_products as it represents your initial version of the data and store_updates represents diffs to that initial version.